# SSL - Nginx Error When Making Request To API Upstream

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, unicorn

SSL is running fine on my `frontend_server`. However, when my front end makes a request to the unicorn API server (on the same server, just running in a Unicorn process), I get the following error: `GET https://198.211.116.68/api/posts?page=1&per_page=30 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`. Why is this the case?

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream frontend_server {
    server 198.211.116.68:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    #return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    server_name dailydownbeat.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://dailydownbeat.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    root /home/rails/dailydownbeat;
    server_name dailydownbeat.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/rails/dailydownbeat/config/ssl/dailydownbeat.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/rails/dailydownbeat/config/ssl/dailydownbeat.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend_server/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }

    location ^~ /api/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass https://app_server/api/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer: my server call was using the IP address. When I changed my server call to use the domain name everything was fine.

I hope my stupid mistake helps someone.